# Is there a way to disable denormals in numpy? (Enabling ftz and daz flags)

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I'm trying to perform a few calculations on floating point numbers that are close to the float32 min. I want the numbers to be flushed to zero when they drop below the float32 minimum instead of switching to subnormals. Is there a way to do this in numpy? I found a package from chainer that tries to do this but it didn't work. (https://github.com/chainer/daz)

Answer (score 0):

`daz` seems to work with numpy.
The observed behavior in this question is due to differences between float32 and float64.

https://github.com/chainer/daz/issues/4